# unable to chain animation in jquery

Tags: jquery, animation, chaining

I have a list which is hidden using css code {display:none;}

now i am using the jquery code to animate the list (li's)

```
var numb = $("ol#update li").length;
 for(j=0; j < numb; j++) {                    
  $("ol#update li").eq(j).animate({
    height: 'show',
opacity: 'show'
}, {duration:1000});
  }
```

I need to animate the items one after the other

there's an example in this [page](http://pradyut.dyndns.org/WebApplicationSecurity/divcomment.jsp)

but all the li's are being animated all at once and i cannot possibly see why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use this instead:

```
var $li = $("ol#update li");
function animate_li(){
   $li.filter(':first')
      .animate({
         height:  'show',
         opacity: 'show'
      }, 1000, function(){
        animate_li();
      });
  $li = $li.not(':first');
}
animate_li();
```

Basically it grabs all the `li`s, and then one by one animates them in. At the same time, each iteration removes the first element from the list. If you wanted it to animate the other way around, replace both occurances of `:first` with `:last`.

Comment: The queue is set per element, not per collection by default. So using a queue is out of the question for the most part. There may be some base abstraction of their Queue you could utilize, but I am not sure, and it would still involve a loop at least to set it up.

Comment: I have another question: -
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2408099/not-able-to-remove-nested-lists-in-a-jquery-variable