# not able to remove nested lists in a jQuery variable

Tags: jquery, nested-lists, html-lists

I have a nested oredered list which i m animating using this code...

```
               var $li = $("ol#update li");
                function animate_li(){
                   $li.filter(':first')
                      .animate({
                         height:  'show',
                         opacity: 'show'
                      }, 500, function(){
                        animate_li();
                      });
                  $li = $li.not(':first');
                }
                animate_li();
```

now i want **not** to show or animate the nested lists(ol s)  or the li s in the ols

take a look at the example [here](http://pradyut.dyndns.org/WebApplicationSecurity/divcomment.jsp)

The structure of my ols are

```
 <ol>
 <li class="bar248">
        <div class="nli">
        <div class="pic">
            <img src="dir/anonymous-thumb.png"alt="image" />
        </div>
        <div align="left" class="text">
        <span>
                <span class="delete_button"><a href="#" id="test" class="delete_update">R</a></span>

                test shouted <span class="timestamp"> 2010/02/24 18:34:26 </span> <br />
        this
        </span>
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="padd">

        </div>
        <ol class="comment">
            <li>                       
                    <div>Testing </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                    <div>Another Test </div>
            </li>

        </ol>

    </li>

  </ol>
```

I m able to hide the nested ols using this code...

```
      $("ol#update li ol").hide();
```

But still time is being consumed in animating them although they are hidden

I m not able to remove the nested li s using this code

```
var $li = $("ol#update li").not("ol#update li ol");
$li = $li.not("ol#update li ol");
```

Take a look at this [here](http://pradyut.dyndns.org/WebApplicationSecurity/divcomment.jsp)

Any help

thanks 
Pradyut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting up your original list like this:

```
var $li = $("ol#update > li");
```

That will get only the `<li>` elements that are direct children of the `<ol id="update">` list.

If you've already got `$li` set up without the ">", then you can remove the "nested" `<li>` elements from that list using "filter":

```
var $li = $('ol#update li'); // gets all <li> elements, even the nested ones

// ...

var $notNested = $li.filter('ol#update > li');
// or, if you prefer,
var $notNested = $li.filter(':not(ol#update li ol li)');
```

Comment: well another question....
i can get the 1st element using this...
$li = $("ol#update li:eq(0)");
how do get the first n elements (only lis) using some code...
thanks

Comment: I can get the first n elements using this...
$("ol#update li:lt(n)");
how do i get the elements between 5 and 10.
please reply...

Comment: I m using $li = $li.filter(':lt(5)').filter(':gt(2)');
to get lis between 5 and 2;
are there other better methods???